# Create group within group with VBA excel

Tags: excel, vba, grouping

So in my file i have a column that looks like this :

```
4
4
4
5
5
5
4
3...
```

the successive 4s need to be grouped together, then successive 5s together and the 5s are a subgroup of 4. I wrote a code that works for the 5s but once i execute it for the 4s it doesn't create new subgroups but includes the 4s in the groups that already exist (or something like that) :

```
Sub Button1_Click()
Dim c As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim alpha As Integer
Dim lim As Long
lim = 15000
alpha = 4
Do while alpha <> 1
For i = 11 To lim
If Cells(i, 2) = alpha Then
c = c + 1
End If

If Cells(i, 2) <> alpha And c <> 0 Then
Range(Cells(i - 1, 2), Cells(i - c, 2)).Select
Selection.Rows.Group
c = 0
End If

Next
alpha = alpha - 1
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: "Group" has a technical meaning in a Pivot Table and the range `Group` method is related to that. Your question doesn't seem to be about that, so I am not sure what your question actually is. Are you trying to rearrange the values in a column in a certain way (e.g. all 4s then all 5s then all 3s in your example)?

Comment: @JohnColeman  Perhaps the poster wants to group rows or create some kind of outline ?

Comment: @Gary'sStudent I think you are right. The documentation suggests that `Group` should only be called on a single cell which is a field header in a pivot table (or something like that -- I've never used the method) so it is mysterious what they expect that method to accomplish when applied to multiple cells which play no role in a pivot table. It would be helpful if they describe intended output more clearly.

Comment: Yes that was the idea 5s then 4s then 3s.... The instructions inside the do while loop do what i want perfectly for one number let's say 5 but when i want to do it for 4s then 3s it doesn't work.

Comment: Do i need to use shapes maybe? i am not familiar with it but if it gets the job done i can read about it

Comment: Based on your comments to my (deleted) answer -- I think that what you want to do is to hide rows in a hierarchical manner and use a `TreeView` control to hide/unhide them. It should be possible though not easy. See http://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?194-Using-a-Treeview-Control for some ideas. You could have the control in a modeless userform, or you could perhaps embed it directly in the worksheet.

Comment: Yes that looks like what i am trying to do. I would prefer it to be embed directly in the work. Thanks for the link i'll dig into that